# NLP techniques for evaluating grammatical correctness?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I'm curious about applying NLP to predict/evaluate someone's level of education (or adherence to correct grammar, spelling, etc.) by analyzing text written by them.

It would be something like: f(t) = s where t is a text and s is some score which rates the grammatical correctness of that text.

Does that exist? I don't know how to search for it. If it does, I'd like some references to relevant papers or algorithms.

Comment: Start with Flesch/Flesch-Kincaid etc. You could factor in spelling and grammar but it won’t add much to a more-general readability score.

Comment: Check out [jury](https://github.com/obss/jury), which kind of does what you need in functionality, but most of the evaluation metrics are designed for machine translation, and thus require reference. However, one thing you can do is just feed your text to an LM and compute perplexity (this would be nearly grammatical correctness).

Answer (score 0):

It does not exist. "Grammatical correctness" is a vague concept anyway, as there is no complete grammatical description of any given language. Also, we all speak and write different variations of our language, which cannot be captured by a single grammar. A language is basically the union of all the individual variants that its speakers produce.

Leaving aside these linguistic philosophy issues, there is also no formal grammar of even a single variant of a language that you could use as a benchmark. I guess the nearest thing you could do is come up with a couple of heuristics and simple rules (which I assume commercial grammar checkers use), checking for example that *reads* always occurs after a third person singular noun. If you have a sufficient number of such heuristics, you can get an idea if a given text is grammatical according to the definition that grammaticality is equivalent to not breaking the rules you encoded.

However, language is very flexible, and hard to capture in rules. Sometimes a sentence might sound like an error, but then in a given context it is fine. If it was easy, someone would already have done it, and primary school teachers could focus their efforts on tasks other than teaching basic grammar...

You can probably capture a number of 'mistakes' easily, but I wouldn't want to guess what coverage you would get; there will be a lot of issues you cannot capture easily.